# How are the data structures which are created for making searches fast in a system design actually stored?

Tags: yelp, quadtree, system-design

Suppose I am designing a system for restaurant recommendations like Yelp. Some of the basic things I need to implement would be like:

1. Users should be able to add/delete/update Places.
2. Given their location (longitude/latitude), users should be able to find all nearby places within a given radius.
3. Users should be able to add feedback/review about a place. The feedback can have pictures, text, and a rating.

From the storage perspective, I decide to have fields like LocationId for each place, Latitude, Longitude, Name, Description and Rating. Assuming around 8 bytes for each LocationId and Latitudes and Longitudes, if I design the system for 500 million locations, I come up with ~ 500 x 10^6 MB of storage requirement. So far, so good.

For getting the location query result faster, I decide to use Quadtree as shown in the image consisting of grids, where each grid consists of 500 locations. If a grid exceeds 500 locations, it is split to form another grid, with max grids at each level to be 4. Lets say I have created the Quadtree as well. I am not sure that after creating the Quatree, **where** and **how** are we storing this tree?

[image: QuadTree created for storing data for Yelp type of system design]

One possible way that I could think of is that I would serialize the Quadtree and on some similar lines like we serialize an n-ary tree and store it in a text file. Considering that I keep LocationId, Longitude and Latitude details in the nodes of my tree, I would need to store 24kb of data for every location if each field is of 8 bytes. For 500 such location, the total memory requirement for my tree would be ~24 * 500M = 12 GB. Whenever my machine restart, I would just de-serialize the stored tree and perform query operations as requested by server.

One problem I see with this approach is that I would need to update my file every time after some regular intervals in order to keep the latest information about locations.

Can anyone suggest in what other ways can store the QuadTree and where will I store it? I believe there are much better ways to store the QuadTree as I suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadtrees are fine for in-memory, but when storing data, DBMSs usually use some kind of R-Tree, for example [R*Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree) or Sort-Tile-Recursive R-Trees (STR-Trees). R-Trees are optimized such that one nodes fits on a disk pages. STR-Trees are best for bulk loading the whole data once and then offering best performance. R*Trees are better suited to scenarios where you wish to add/move/remove individual points.

From a performance perspective, it may also be better to use less than 500 entries per quadtree node, how about 10 or 50?

If you want to play around with different spatial trees, have a look [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) or [here](http://www.phtree.org) (all in Java).